# Strange Label shown on tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom cells in my app. When the user selects a cell, a detail View Controller is shown. When back to the tableView, a label with the text Label appears for about 10 seconds, then it dissappears.
I have searched for the label in the storyBoard, but I cannot find it, but the most strange thing  is that it only appears when the users goes back from the detail viewController to the tableViewController.

Here is an image from what I am talking about:

[image]

Any idea on how to detect the Label in the code is welcome.

UPDATED**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell ==nil){
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }


    cell.nombreEmpresaLabel.text = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"nombreEmpresa"];


    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  cell.direccionEmpresaLabel.text= [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"direccionEmpresa"];


    NSMutableString *logo = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"http://mujercanariasigloxxi.appgestion.eu/logos/"];
    NSString *imageURL = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"strImagen"];


    cell.meGustaHits.text = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"valoracionEmpresa"];




    if(imageURL != nil && ![imageURL isEqual:[NSNull null]])
    {
        [logo appendString:imageURL];
        NSURL *logoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:logo];
        NSData *logoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:logoURL];
        cell.logoImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:logoData];
    }
    else{
        cell.logoImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icono80"];
    }



    return cell;
}
```

[image]

As you can see, there are only three labels, one for the company name, one for the company address and the third to show a number.

Comment: Is your tableViewController has ProtoType cells defined in the StoryBoard?

Comment: Yes @Srikanth, it has ProtoType cells defined in the StoryBoard.

Comment: I guess you are loading custom cells programatically. Try removing ProtoType cells once from storyBoard and also give a thorough check in your StoryBoard and program for any UILabels.

Comment: @Srikanth, I have removed the ProtoType cells from storyBoard, and no label is there.

Comment: @meda, I have updated my question including cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: @mvasco does the label scroll, is it always on the 2nd cell

Comment: Yes @meda, it appears when back from detailView to the tableView, but this is not always on the 2nd cell, it is always at the same place, may be not the 2nd cell, it depends on the scrolling point before opening the detailView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it's hard to find control on your storyboard.

It seems to me you added it by accident.

If you did not create it with code then you should see it in `Document outline` of the storyboard.

[image]

Comment: Thank you meda, I don't know if I added it by accident, but I don't know now how to remove it. Please take a look at my updated question where I have just added a screenshot from my scene, to discard that the 'magical' label is there. Thank you.

Comment: No, it is not there, I have also searched in the storyBoard viewed as source code, I have found the three labels from the custom cell, but not the magical label...any advice where I should continue searching?

Comment: I advice you to recreate your view, its not worth your time (you posted this 5 hours ago!) to look for magical label, drag a new viewcontroller next to this one and copy paste your view controls;)

Answer (score 1):

do you see the "Label" text always in the same position? or does it depend on the cell that you pressed? …. I would suggest doing a search by console on your storyboards / xibs.
Please go to  your project directory in console and use the following command to check if some UI element has the text Label:

```
find . -name "*.storyboard" -exec grep "Label" {} \; -print
```

If you also have xibs files perform the same command for "*.xib"

Comment: Thank you Barbara, it always appears in the same position.

Comment: Barbara, your search command throws this: ./Downloads/Vive Gran Canaria 0-1-8/Vive Gran Canaria/Base.lproj/Main_iPhone.storyboard
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="1EE-Ar-TXs" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>

Comment: mvasco, I don't see any "Label" text value in the command output… it seems none of your storyboards contain the word "Label"… which makes me consider the possibility that the Label is being added programatically… Are you building your interface or part of it programatically at some point of your app? . If you're able to share the code I'd give it a quick look to try to detect from where the "Label" text is coming from

Comment: It is solved, it was a label from the detailViewController. Thank you for your time and effort.